# how to slice specific characters in python with constraints?

Tags: python, string, character, slice

```
str="class computer :"
name=str[str.find("class"):str.find(":")]
print name
```

The above code has to output the result as `" computer "` for which I get, `"class computer"`. what might be the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Once you `.find('class')` you need to offset that index by the length of the string `'class'` itself.

```
>>> s = 'class computer :'
>>> s[s.find('class')+len('class'):s.find(':')]
' computer '
```

You could throw on a `strip` to remove the leading and trailing whitespace

```
>>> s[s.find("class")+len('class'):s.find(":")].strip()
'computer'
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.find` returns the index of the first occurring character match and hence `0` is returned

```
>>> s.find('class')
0
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

> Return the **lowest index** in the string where substring sub is found

Thus you need to add the length of your `find` string to get the correct output by using the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function

```
>>> name=s[s.find("class")+len('class'):s.find(":")]
>>> print name
 computer
```

Note - You should not use `str` as a variable as it shadows the built-in functionality

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable name!!

Comment: Might be easier splitting after finding class

Comment: The best way is `s.split('class')[1][:-1]`. But do we add that?

Comment: I think the best way is `s.split()[1]` ;)

Comment: Naw! He wants the leading and trailing whitespaces!

Comment: he/she would actually need a regex to actually do it properly, `s =" myclass has a class computer :" -> s.find("class") -> 3` and it will fail for a million other cases also

Comment: Yeah, we better wait for him/her (OP) to respond!

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other word with class in it your find will fail, you can use a regex with word boundaries to find an exact match for the word `class`:

```
import  re

print(re.findall(r"(?<=\bclass\b)\s+\w+\s+",s))
```

You can see an example of how it will fail:

```
In [9]: s = "subclass class computer :"

In [10]: s[s.find('class')+len('class'):s.find(':')]
Out[10]: ' class computer '

In [11]: re.findall(r"(?<=\bclass\b)\s+\w+\s+",s)
Out[11]: [' computer ']
```

If you have more than one `class` in your string you can use a lookahead with the lookbehind assertion:

```
 s = "subclass class tv class computer :"
 print(re.findall(r"(?<=\bclass\b)\s+\w+\s+(?=:)",s))

 [' computer ']
```

Comment: A complete answers! ;)